# Chrome extension webrequest network xhr exception

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, webrequest

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that routes certain requests to another.  I've found a couple resources on how to do that and I've gotten it half working.  Here is the extension code:

```
var requestRoutingTable = { 
    'some/url/i/want/to/catch' : 'libs/TVKeyValue.js'
};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){
    for (var key in requestRoutingTable){
        if (details.url.indexOf(key) != -1){
            console.log('redirecting to: ' + chrome.extension.getURL(requestRoutingTable[key]));
            return {redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL(requestRoutingTable[key])};
        }   
    }   
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

To test whether this works, I wrote the following in jQuery and loaded the extension:

```
$.getScript('some/url/i/want/to/catch', function(script, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // this doesn't get here!
}
```

Symptoms:

- I see that the console.log from the extension code gets triggered
- I see that the actual file get loaded through the chrome extension (through the network tab in the developer tools

Problems:

The callback doesn't get triggered.  Suspiciously, the original request stays in the "pending" status.

The point of this extension is to place some stubs/mock responses for certain requests.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I notice that the page you subbing in is a page within your extension.  Is it included in `web_accessible_resources` in your manifest?  It might not make a difference, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: yep, its included, no error is thrown and I can actually see the file being loaded through the network

Comment: You didn't run your test on an extension page, did you? You should run your test on a pages served with an `http;//` protocol.  Depending on how `getScript` actually operates, the `manifest_vesion:2` ban on inline scripts may stop it from completing if run on an extension page.

Comment: More generaly, have you confirmed that `getScript` runs correctly without the webRequest redirect? Or perhaps the script you substitute in has an error that is not reported by jQyery? Try a trivially simple script, if you aren't already.

Comment: I ran it extension on a locally hosted webserver.  The page is supposed to be making a couple of xhr requests, but after turning on the extension, it doesn't seem to forward those requests correctly (ie, the callback is not called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may be an issue with Chrome extensions, I have reported it as a possible bug here:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=145074